# How can I delete specific rows from a table?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with `n` number of rows. The value of `n` changes/updates every minute.
The first `<td>` of every row will either contain some text, or it will be blank.
I want to delete/remove all the rows except, the first row and the row whose first cell contains the text `'xyz'`.
So, how will I be able to do this?
This `table` element is stored in the variable `parentTable`.

I'm kind of new to javascript and programming. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I tested it with just the second row, but nothing happened even though the text is not `xyz` in the cell.

```
if(parentNode.childNodes[1].innerText !== "xyz")
parentTable.deleteRow[1];
```

And how do I loop around every row and do this?

EDIT: HTML for first cell in every row.

```
<td class=wbwhite align=center width=40 style="border-top: none; border-left:none; border-right:none;">
&nbsp;
<a href="www.kasdjfkasd.sadsdk.comi" class=pi>xyz</a>
&nbsp;
</td>
```

Comment: Where is your code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var table = parentTable;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for ( var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++ )
    {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var val=  row.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML.toString();

        if ( 'xyz' != val )
        {
            table.deleteRow( i );

            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if the 'xyz' was wrapped within <a> tag? What will I have to change then? Refer question for html.

Comment: <a>xyz</a>....... Did you see the HTML? Can I use row.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML; instead?

Comment: I tried and all rows got deleted :( and isn't it supposed to be innerText?

Comment: still doesn't work. All rows are being deleted. Got error "...has no method 'text'"

Comment: I tried row.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML and it returns xyz !!  May be you have to use row.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML.toString()

Comment: I think that the nbsp was a problem. I managed to get it working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code (pure JavaScript):

(assuming table has id = `tableId`).

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('#tableId > tbody > tr');

// i = 1 not i = 0 to keep the first row.
for (var i = 1; i < all.length; i++) {
    var td = all[i].querySelectorAll('td')[0];
    if ( td.textContent != "xyz" ) {
        all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var allRows = parentTable.getElementsByTagName('TR');

for(var i=1; i<allRows.length;)
{
    var tr = allRows[i];
    var firstTd = tr.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0];
    if(firstTd.innerHTML !== 'xyz')
    {
        tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    }else{
        i++;
    }
}
```